# Twitter Bootstrap Carousel, click on dot 1 or 2 activates images, but on dot 3 or 4 no reaction

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am trying to use the Bootstrap Carousel with 4 images.
When I click on the dot number 1 or 2 the images are shown immediately as expected (ok). 
But when I click on the dot number 3 or 4 the images are not shown immediately (NOK). 
All 4 images are shown one by one when a time of 30 seconds has expired (ok). 
A click on the left-arrow (or right-arrow) lets show the previous (or next) image immediately (ok).

The source for the index.html and styles.css can be found here: 
https://jsfiddle.net/leventy7/ow6stx67/2/

```
<!-- Indicators -->
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active" id="carousel-indicator-li-id1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1" id="carousel-indicator-li-id2"></li>
    <li data target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2" id="carousel-indicator-li-id3"></li>
    <li data target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="3" id="carousel-indicator-li-id4"></li>
</ol>
```

The result (with the images for the carousel) can be seen here:
http://test-my-bs-carousel.bitballoon.com/

I would really appreciate it, if someone could give me a hint. I'm relative new to CSS and Bootstrap.

Thank you very much and kind regards

Levent

Comment: Its working https://jsfiddle.net/cmedina/ow6stx67/3/ what is your problem??

Comment: The issue is: _But when I click on the dot number 3 or 4 the images are not shown immediately (NOK)._

Comment: I assume that you agree that a mouse click on the dot number 3 or 4 do not let show yet the image number 3 or 4 immediately. If you still think that it's working normal than please let me know. Otherwise I would really appreciate it when somebody could give me a hint to fix the issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied the file from your fiddle and tried it out on my own. The problem was with your html file. You missed a hyphen in your data target.

```
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
<li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active" id="carousel-indicator-li-id1"></li>
<li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1" id="carousel-indicator-li-id2"></li>
<li data target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2" id="carousel-indicator-li-id3"></li>
<li data target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="3" id="carousel-indicator-li-id4"></li>
```

Here is the right code snippet.

```
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active" id="carousel-indicator-li-id1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1" id="carousel-indicator-li-id2"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2" id="carousel-indicator-li-id3"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="3" id="carousel-indicator-li-id4"></li>
</ol>
```

[**DEMO IN JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/ow6stx67/5/)

Comment: Thank you very very much. I did not understand yet at which position which character was missing or was wrong exactly, but with your code it works successful now. Wish you a great week.

Comment: More than willing to help. :)